# dbca error: UnsatisfiedLinkError exception loading native library: njni19

Tags: dbca

I am installing oracle19c on OEL9.2
When i run dbca, the setuo will start and it will throw the below exception

```
[oracle@ORA19 dbhome_1]$ dbca
UnsatisfiedLinkError exception loading native library: njni19
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/lib/libnjni19.so: /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntshcore.so.19.1: file too short
```

How to resolve this?

i tried installing all the prerequisites